How can I hide a BottomNavigationBarItem on Flutter?
I have something like this
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _screens = const [
    TopNavigator(),
    SearchScreen(),
    SettingsScreen(),
    SelectedAlbumScreen()
  ];

  void setSelectedScreen(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }


 BottomNavigationBar(
                      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: 'Search'),
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: 'Settings'),
                      ],
                      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
                      selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
                      onTap: (int index) {
                        setSelectedScreen(index);
                      },
                    ),


As you can see, I have 4 screens in my list, but only 3 declared in my BottomNavigationBar, so I need to have those 4 screens available to go to them but the number 4 must be hidden for the user so that it can only be accessed by tapping on some button.
When I switch to the screen via code, I get an assertion error.
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              context.read<HandleBottomNavigationIndex>().setSelectedScreen(3);
            }

Failed assertion: line 251 pos 15: '0 <= currentIndex && currentIndex < items.length': is not true.

Assertion error is because of you have declare 4 screens in _screens list and in your BottomNavigationBar you have 3 BottomNavigationBarItems.

I have added code to resolve issue.

can you share the code where you use the _screens variable?

Try below code...
bool showItem = true;

void setSelectedScreen(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < _screens.length) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
      });
    }
  }

List<BottomNavigationBarItem> get _visibleItems {
final items = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
  const BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
    label: 'Home',
  ),
  const BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
    label: 'Search',
  ),
  const BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
    label: 'Settings',
  ),
  if (showItem)
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.album), 
      label: 'Album',
    ),
];
return items;
 }

And in your build method
final visibleScreens = showItem
        ? _screens
        : _screens.sublist(0, 3); 

body: visibleScreens[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        items: _visibleItems,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setSelectedScreen(index);
        },
      ),

Change showItem true/false as your requirement in setState

thanks for your answer it works well almost like what I had in mind, but I need my 3 BottomNavigationBarItem to be always on screen and the number 4 always hidden, I tried to place the properties of this last one in  ´icon: SizedBox.shrink(), label: ''´ but even though it is not visible it takes up space in my BottomNavigationBar.

Do you need an invisible 4th BottomNavigationBarItem with Space Occupy?

It seems that by the very nature of the BottomNavigationBar it is impossible to have a number of screens different from the number of items in the BottomNavigationBar.
but I was able to solve it just by creating my own BottomNavigationBar.
here is the code:
item:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomBottomNavigationBarItem {
  final IconData icon;
  final String label;

  const CustomBottomNavigationBarItem(
      {required this.icon, required this.label});
}

BottomNavigatonBar:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:palm_player/presentation/widgets/bottom_navigator/custom_bottom_navigation_bar_item.dart';

class CustomBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<CustomBottomNavigationBarItem> items;
  final void Function(int index) onTap;
  final int selectedIndex;
  final Color? selectedItemColor;
  final Color? unselectedItemColor;
  final Color? backgroundColor;

  const CustomBottomNavigationBar(
      {super.key,
      required this.items,
      required this.onTap,
      required this.selectedIndex,
      this.backgroundColor = Colors.white,
      this.selectedItemColor = Colors.black,
      this.unselectedItemColor = Colors.grey})
      : assert(items.length >= 2);

  @override
  State<CustomBottomNavigationBar> createState() =>
      _CustomBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _CustomBottomNavigationBarState extends State<CustomBottomNavigationBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double bottomNavigationBarHeight =
        kBottomNavigationBarHeight + (kBottomNavigationBarHeight * 0.2);
    return Container(
      height: bottomNavigationBarHeight,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: widget.backgroundColor),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          const Spacer(),
          ...widget.items.asMap().entries.map((currentItem) => Expanded(
                  child: InternalItem(
                icon: currentItem.value.icon,
                label: currentItem.value.label,
                onTap: widget.onTap,
                index: currentItem.key,
                color: widget.selectedIndex == currentItem.key
                    ? widget.selectedItemColor!
                    : widget.unselectedItemColor!,
              ))),
          const Spacer()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InternalItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  final IconData icon;
  final String label;
  final Color color;
  final void Function(int index) onTap;
  const InternalItem(
      {super.key,
      required this.icon,
      required this.label,
      required this.onTap,
      required this.index,
      required this.color});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        onTap(index);
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Icon(
            icon,
            color: color,
          ),
          Text(
            label,
            style: TextStyle(color: color, fontSize: 11),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



implementation:
CustomBottomNavigationBar(
                      selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      items: const <CustomBottomNavigationBarItem>[
                        CustomBottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: Icons.home, label: 'Home'),
                        CustomBottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: Icons.search, label: 'Search'),
                        CustomBottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: Icons.settings, label: 'Settings')
                      ],
                      onTap: (int index) {
                        setSelectedScreen(index);
                      },
                    ),

```


